# overriding default User-Agent in Crawl Spider

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am having trouble overriding default User-Agent in Crawl Spider template.I am trying to define the User-Agent in start_requests method like this

```
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url ="https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating", headers ={'User-Agent':self.user_agent})

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths= '//h3[@class="lister-item-header"]/a'), callback="parse_item", follow=True, process_request = 'set_user_agent'),)

    def set_user_agent(self, request):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] =self.user_agent
        return request

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath('//div[@class="sc-b5e8e7ce-1 kNhUtn"]/h1[@class="sc-b73cd867-0 gLtJub"]/text()').get()
        }
```

and I got an error like this

```
  File "/mnt/c/Users/asib0/OneDrive/scrapy_project1/scrapy-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 35, in process_spider_output_async
    async for r in result or ():
  File "/mnt/c/Users/asib0/OneDrive/scrapy_project1/scrapy-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 116, in process_async
    async for r in iterable:
  File "/mnt/c/Users/asib0/OneDrive/scrapy_project1/scrapy-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 129, in _parse_response
    for request_or_item in self._requests_to_follow(response):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/asib0/OneDrive/scrapy_project1/scrapy-env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 105, in _requests_to_follow
    yield rule.process_request(request, response)
TypeError: BestMovieSpider.set_user_agent() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
2023-03-06 17:56:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

How to set the User-Agent properly in Crawl Spider template ?

Answer (score 2):

Use custom settings to set the user agent for all requests...  It is much easier.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class BestMovieSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "best_movie"
    allowed_domains = ["www.imdb.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating"]
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths= '//h3[@class="lister-item-header"]/a'), callback="parse_item", follow=True)

  def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath('//div[@class="sc-b5e8e7ce-1 kNhUtn"]/h1[@class="sc-b73cd867-0 gLtJub"]/text()').get()
        }
```

Comment: Where is the custom being executed in this code? Can you describe Kindly?

Comment: It is run by the scrapy framework. @AsibAhmed  Scrapy has a built in `UserAgentMiddleware` that extracts the User Agent from the settings and injects it into the request header.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the request as well. As your `set_user_agent` method requires `request` as an argument. check the below code, this will fix the error.

```
def start_requests(self):
    request = scrapy.Request(url="https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=drama&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating")
    request = self.user_agent(request)
    yield request
```